# Need to hide the class according to the directory opened

Tags: php, jquery, function, recursion

I'm new here and a beginner. I will try to elaborate my problem and so please try to understand and respond and thanks for your help in advance.
QUESTION:I had just taken the details of a directory named images and for which the output exists, but whereas I'm in need to make this directories to show one by one.
i.e,my response before adding jquery was shown below:

```
hari/
            1/
                Kick Buttowski5.png
                hari1.1/
                    Kick Buttowski0.png
                    kick_buttowski.png
            2/
                Kick Buttowski0.png
                kick_buttowski.png
            3/
                Kick Buttowski0.png
            Kick Buttowski5.png

        hari1/

            2/
                Kick Buttowski0.png
                kick_buttowski.png
            kick_buttowski.png

        hari2/

            Kick Buttowski5.png

and the response after jquery was:

hari/
hari1/
hari2/
```

So I just want the output as specified below if I click hari directory alone:

```
  hari/
        1/
            Kick Buttowski5.png
            hari1.1/
        2/
        3/
    hari1/
    hari2/
```

And output as follows if if I click hari/hari1.1/ directory alone

1/
        Kick Buttowski5.png
        hari1.1/
            Kick Buttowski0.png
            kick_buttowski.png
    2/
    3/
hari1/
hari2/

Likewise for each and every individual folders one by one. Sorry for this long confusing description, but am not sure how to explain short. I hope this could be solved as soon as possible.

Here is my code that I used :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Reading a Tree of Files and Folders</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                a = $('#counn').val();
                var checkBoxClasses = [];
                for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
                    checkBoxClasses += i;
                    $('.hide' + i).toggle();
                }
                var arr =checkBoxClasses.split("");                
                $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
                    x = value;
                    //alert(x);
                    $('.show' + x).click(function () {
                        $('.hide' + $(this).attr('id')).toggle();
                    });

                });

            });

        </script>

        <?php
        $folderPath = "images";

        function readFolder($path) {

            // Open the folder
            if (!( $dir = opendir($path) )) {
                die("Can't open $path");
            }
            $filenames = array();

            // Read the contents of the folder, ignoring '.' and '..', and
            // appending '/' to any subfolder names. Add all the files and
            // subfolders to the $filenames array.

            while ($filename = readdir($dir)) {
                if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..') {
                    if (is_dir("$path/$filename")) {
                        $filename .= '/';
                    }
                    $filenames[] = $filename;
                }
            }

            closedir($dir);

            // Sort the filenames in alphabetical order
            sort($filenames);
            // Display the filenames, and process any subfolders
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo count($filenames); ?> " id="counn">
            <?php
            echo "<ul>";
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
                echo '<li class="show' . $i . '" id=' . $i . ' >' . $filename;
                echo '<div class="hide' . $i . '" >';
                if (substr($filename, -1) == '/') {
                    readFolder("$path/" . substr($filename, 0, -1));
                }
                echo '</div>';
                echo "</li>";

                $i++;
            }

            echo "</ul>";
        }

        echo "<h2>Contents of folder => $folderPath:</h2>";
        readFolder($folderPath);
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Reading a Tree of Files and Folders</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.sss ul').toggle();
                $('.test').click(function () {
                    $(this).parent("li").children("ul").toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
        $folderPath = "images";

        function readFolder($path) {

            if (!( $dir = opendir($path) )) {
                die("Can't open $path");
            }
            $filenames = array();

            while ($filename = readdir($dir)) {
                if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..') {
                    if (is_dir("$path/$filename")) {
                        $filename .= '/';
                    }
                    $filenames[] = $filename;
                }
            }

            closedir($dir);
            sort($filenames);

            $v = '';
            $i = 1;
            echo "<ul class='sss'>";
            foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
                echo "<li><span class='test'>$filename</span>";
                if (substr($filename, -1) == '/') {
                    readFolder("$path/" . substr($filename, 0, -1));
                }
                echo "</li>";
                $i++;
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }

        echo "<h2>Contents of folder => $folderPath:</h2>";
        readFolder($folderPath);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just thought to share the solution that have been used finally, so that some may able to understand my question.! Thanks for your attention . . :)

Comment: Please describe how your answer helps the questioner in detail. Thank you.

Comment: My friend Leonid Glanz, I've asked this question a month ago. Just got the answer and so to let all know about this I've plotted my used solution.